# JavaFX Canvas and BorderPane

Tags: java, javafx, borderpane

I'm currently working on a project in JavaFX and I'm doing the GUI with BorderPane. I have successfully created a menu and accordion, and added them to the positions I wanted (top and right).

Now I've created a class that extends Canvas and want to add it to the left side, but it doesn't seem to be working.

What I need is the app to have a menu, extendable options on the right (accordion) and space to draw images on the remaining space (left).

Can anyone shed some light?

Adding some code!

```
public class PainelCanvas extends Canvas implements DesenhoCanvas {

    //ATRIBUTOS
    Canvas canvas;

    //CONSTRUTOR
    public PainelCanvas() {
        canvas = new Canvas(400, 400);
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        desenhar(gc);
    }

    @Override
    public void desenhar(GraphicsContext gc) {
        gc.setFill(Color.GREEN);
        gc.fillText("adsads", 20, 30);
    }

}
```

In my main class, I'm creating an object of PainelCanvas and adding it to my BorderPane.

```
BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
PainelMenu menu = new PainelMenu();
PainelCanvas canvas = new PainelCanvas();
PainelAccordion painel = new PainelAccordion();

//Definir localização dos vários elementos gráficos
root.setTop(menu);  
root.setLeft(canvas);
root.setRight(painel);
```

Comment: In what way is the class that extends Canvas not working? Is it not displaying anything when you add it to the GUI, or something else?

Comment: It's doesn't display anything when I add it.

Comment: Can you post a [small portion](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code that shows the behavior you're talking about?

Comment: What about `DesenhoCanvas` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your canvas has no width or height set, and no content.

Note that you do

```
public class PainelCanvas extends Canvas ...
```

and

```
PainelCanvas canvas = new PainelCanvas();
// ...
root.setLeft(canvas);
```

So `PainelCanvas` **is a** `Canvas` and is the `Canvas` you add to your `BorderPane`.

Inside the `PainelCanvas` you create another `Canvas`:

```
canvas = new Canvas(400, 400);
```

and add some content to it:

```
GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
// ...
gc.fillText(...);
```

But that canvas is never added to the `BorderPane`.

If you really want to extend `Canvas` (not really recommended) you should do

```
public class PainelCanvas extends Canvas implements DesenhoCanvas {
    public PainelCanvas() {
        super(400, 400);
        GraphicsContext gc = this.getGraphicsContext2D();
        desenhar(gc);
    }
    // desenhar(...) method as before
}
```

But I prefer not to subclass `Node` classes unless really necessary ("favor aggregation over inheritance").

**Recommended solution:**

```
public class PainelCanvas implements DesenhoCanvas {
    private Canvas canvas ;
    public PainelCanvas() {
        canvas = new Canvas(400, 400);
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        desenhar(gc);
    }

    // desenhar(...) as before...

    public Node getView() {
        return canvas ;
    }
}
```

and then:

```
root.setLeft(canvas.getView());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! That works :D and yes, stupid me. I extended canvas and still created a new canvas lol